# I was doing react-hook-form and then I tried using Zod validation, but got an error

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

I got this error

```
export 'transformToNestObject' (imported as 'r') was not found in 'react-hook-form' (possible exports: Controller, Form, FormProvider, appendErrors, get, set, useController, useFieldArray, useForm, useFormContext, useFormState, useWatch)
```

What does it mean?

I tried modifying the file in the node modules but it didn't work